# Start another thread after SwingWorker completes in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, swingworker

I know there many questions on SO but non of them has good enough answer and before asking here I googled a lot specially SO but nothing could make it clear. I just simply wants to start my other thread when my SwingWorker finish its work.

I want to start a timer when the SwingWorker finishes it's work but cannot figure out how.

```
class createGUI extends SwingWorker<Void, Void>
{
    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground() throws Exception
    {
         //Some long processing
    }

    @Override
    protected void done()
    {
         //Doing GUI work here
         prgBar.setInderminent(false);
    }
}

//Starts a progressBar and calls createGUI();
prgBar.setInderminent(true);
new createGUI().execute();
```

Now there is another startTimer Thread which I want to start when this SwingWork finishes.

```
public class startTimer implements Runnable
{
     @Override
     public void run()
     {
         while(true)
         {
             Thread.sleep(1000);
             //Update Database
         }
     }
}
```

But I don't understand how can I do so?

Comment: You probably need to execute another SwingWorker if you don't want the UI to freeze, because updating a database is a long operation. You can start your timer when the second SwingWorker begins and stop/cancel that timer in the `done()` of the second SwingWorker.

Comment: Yes but How would I know that when to start second swing worker or thread instead?

Comment: At the end of the `done()` method in the **first** `SwingWorker`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless I'm missing something, you could pass a reference in the constructor to `createGUI` and start that when `done()`.

```
class createGUI extends SwingWorker<Void, Void>
{
  private Thread startTimer;
  public createGUI(Thread startTimer) {
    this.startTimer = startTimer;
  }
  @Override
  protected Integer doInBackground() throws Exception {
     //Some long processing
  }

  @Override
  protected void done()
  {
     //Doing GUI work here
     prgBar.setInderminent(false);
     startTimer.start();
  }
}
```

You would also need to change

```
new createGUI().execute();
```

to something like

```
new createGUI(new Thread(new startTimer())).execute();
```

Also, class names should start with a capital letter. `CreateGUI` and `StartTimer`

Comment: This will start startTimer Thread as soon as createGUI starts but I want startTimer  to start when Swingworker has finished

Comment: @JavaDrunk No. This will start `startTimer` Thread at the end of the `done()` method of execution. A `Thread` doesn't begin until something calls `start()`.

Comment: If you don't want to spread references around (ie re-use the `SwingWorker` in different ways), you could attach a `PropertyChangeListener` to the `SwingWorker` and monitor the `state` property, as an alternative...

Comment: @MadProgrammer I am not sure but attaching a PropertyChangeListener to the SwingWorker won't it make it a bit lengthy then the one Elliott has suggested? and with that I am amazed that Elliott gave the perfect solution and it's working great. I tried every trick of my sleeves but could think of this.

Comment: @JavaDrunk There's nothing wrong with the example Elliott has provide, except it now couples the worker to a particular work flow and exposes objects to the worker which it probably doesn't need to know anything about in order to do it's job.  I've found recently that the `PropertyChangeListener` support provides a significant amount of flexibility when it comes to designing workers, as I don't need to either design in multiple workflows or extensions to existing workers.  I simply use the `PropertyChangeListener` to make these decisions.

Comment: @JavaDrunk And yes, I agree it is a bit more cumbersome, that's the reason I'm currently designing an extension to the worker (for my personal libraries) to take care of that and provide simpler, more targeted, notifications, but that's another question ;)

Answer (score 1):

*Note: There is nothing wrong with Elliot's answer, expect that it couples the work flow to the worker and passes object references to the worker, which it would otherwise not require (+1 to his answer)*

As an alternative to passing about references to classes which probably don't need to know or care about such things, you could use the `SwingWorker`s `PropertyChangeListener` support.

This decouples the worker and makes it more reusable...

```
CreateGUI worker = new CreateGUI();
worker.addPropertyChangeListener(new PropertyChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
        if ("state".equals(evt.getPropertyName())) {
            SwingWorker.StateValue state = (SwingWorker.StateValue) evt.getNewValue();
            switch (state) {
                case DONE:
                    prgBar.setInderminent(false);
                    startTimer.start();
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
});
worker.execute();
```

Which would simply run...

```
public class CreateGUI extends SwingWorker<Integer, Integer> {

    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground() throws Exception {
        // Working hard or hardly working...
        return ???;
    }
}
```

Just as a side note (as the worker name freaks me out), Swing is NOT thread safe, you should not create or modify UI elements from outside the Event Dispatching Thread...

**Updated...**

If all you want to do is chain the execution of your threads, then you could use a single threaded `ExecutorService`, for example...

```
ExecutorService es = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
es.submit(new CreateGUI());
es.submit(new StartTimer());

es.shutdown();
```

This ensures that `StartTimer` can't run until `CreateGUI` either finishes or fails...

Comment: WOW that's another great solution as I can see it can be handy in some situations as well. I must appreciate your great example. As always Love you MadProgrammer. I already a big fan of yours.

Comment: It can be very helpful when setting ProgressBar with determinent Property. Thanks a lot Man